# Camcorder for filming ballrom dance

Tags: video-camera

I am looking for a camcorder to film ballroom dance events. This means it has to deal well with quickly moving subjects in low, artificially colored light. Full HD resolution should suffice. A microphone input would be a useful addition, so that music can be recorded directly from the sound system.

I try to keep the price point around 500 € at max, but recommendations from different price ranges are also appreciated.